# Finding Equivalent Thevenin Resistence

Tags: voltage, pic, resistors

For the following circuit:

[circuit image http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/674/aBkkRU.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/674/aBkkRU.png)

I'm solving for the Rth at node 2. In the solution guide, it shows that the Rth = (10k || 10k). I don't understand how this is so, by following the resistence equivalent rules, these two resistance should be in series.

I'd appreciation for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume for node 2 you're ignoring everything to the right of it?

Anyways, to calculate the [Thévenin equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin's_theorem), you look at short-circuited current and open-circuit voltage. If you just want resistance (if you have V<sub>Th</sub> and I<sub>Th</sub>, then R = V/I), replace voltage sources with shorts and current sources with opens.

For just resistance, if we replace the 10 V DC source with a short, then we can see that it's just two 10 kΩ resistors in parallel just like your guide shows.  To check it, we could find V<sub>Th</sub> and I<sub>Th</sub>.

V<sub>Th</sub> = 5 V, a simple voltage divider between equal resistors. I<sub>Th</sub> = 1 mA (10 V, 10 kΩ).

$$R_{th} = \frac{V_{th}}{I_{th}} = \frac{5\mathrm{\ V}}{1\mathrm{\ mA}} = 5\mathrm{\ k\Omega} = 10\mathrm{\ k\Omega} \parallel 10\mathrm{\ k\Omega}$$